# Cassandra-Django python application approach

Tags: python, django, orm, cassandra

i am working on developing a Django application with Cassandra as the back end database. while Django supports ORM feature for SQL, i wonder if there is any thing similar for Cassandra.
what would be the best approach to load the schema into the Cassandra server and perform CRUD operations.
P.S. I am complete beginner to Cassandra.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's an external backend for Cassandra, but it has some issues with the authentication middleware, which doesn't handle users correctly in the admin. If you use a non-relational database, you lose a lot of goodies that django has. You could try using Postgres' nosql extension for the parts of your data that you want to store in a nosql'y way, and the regular Postgres' tables for the rest.

Answer (score 0):

I initially started out with the same question, but as raphonic points out, Postgres is well supported by Django and Postgres actually can be used both relationally and as a NoSQL database, with [comparable performance to bespoke systems (WARNING: PDF)](https://wiki.postgresql.org/images/b/b4/Pg-as-nosql-pgday-fosdem-2013.pdf) like Cassandra, CouchDB, MongoDB, etc.

For those that are interested in doing this, you should look into using postgres with hstore (and possibly indexing with GIN or GiST), or [postgres with JSON](http://blog.endpoint.com/2013/06/postgresql-as-nosql-with-data-validation.html) (XML is also an option if you hate yourself).

In the end, unless you're doing something that really fits/requires the use case of the new and sexy databases mentioned above, you can almost certainly use Postgres and not lose many of it's great features.